# remove oracle user without uninstalling oracle ubuntu16.04

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, ubuntu-16.04

I installed oracle xe 11g in my ubuntu 16.04 machine following the steps given in [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Its working totally fine but while installing it created a ubuntu user 'oracle' in my laptop. (Though I have configured oracle with user as 'arman' later) I tried to remove this user with 'sudo deluser oracle' but then my oracle software got currupted and I had to reinstall it. So Now again I have that same oracle user in my machine. But I want to get rid of it. Please Tell me how to remove this 'oracle' user without affecting the software.
Thanx in advance!!!

Comment: It's a little late but we've used successfully the docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/wnameless/oracle-xe-11g/

Comment: How have you "configured oracle with user as 'arman'"? What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry for writing it in a very non-sense way. Actually I added user arman to group dba (as it was an step given in the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04)) by doing:   sudo usermod -a -G dba arman

Comment: That doesn't change the ownership of any files in the installation, or make the `oracle` user expendable. It does allow you to connect as `sys` from your own account, I suppose. So, why do you want to get rid of it? What harm is it doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Your user 'arman' is a database user, known only to your database - if you shut down the database, there is no 'arman' on your laptop. Or, if you also have an 'arman' operating system user (set up in Linux), the two are unrelated. The 'oracle' user is needed as the owner of the file structure you created on your system. If you also have an 'arman' user set up in Linux, you may try to (recursively) change the owner of all the 'oracle' files and directories to 'arman' (the Linux user!) and if that works you can remove 'oracle'. But someone must own the oracle files on Linux.

Comment: I think you are correct. To clarify the question, 'arman' is the Linux user and as a super user also I think I would own oracle files also. But as I am very new on linux OS, I don't know how to " try to (recursively) change the owner of all the 'oracle' files and directories to 'arman' (the Linux user!)" as you said.

Comment: @Arman - see the `chown` command (`man chown`). See the `-R` option for recursive change (meaning, change the ownership of folder and its files and subfolders). The trick will be to find ALL the folders on which you need to make this change, before attempting to remove the oracle user. BUT: Why does the `oracle` user bother you on the OS? Why not leave it alone?

Comment: Thanx. I'll better leave it as it is. Actually I thought that in this way if in future i'll install some other software then that may also create users and in this way after a few month I may get so many unnecessary users.